# When I try to make migrations in django I get an error of undefined DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web

I made a change to my `models.py` and then
I have entered this line to make migrations:

```
django-admin makemigrations
```

and got this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting 
INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define 
the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have tried defining the environment variable by `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` but seems to have no effect.

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-admin` [doesn't include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/) the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value. You can either use `manage.py` which will specify it for you

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

Or you'll have to specify the settings  module in the command

```
django-admin makemigrations --settings=mysite.settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't run django-admin. Use manage.py makemigrations instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `manage.py`, not `django-admin`.